CSRF Token and Cookies Sent with Axios in a Next.js [CSRF token mismatch error]
I'm working on a Next.js application where I need to handle user registration with proper CSRF protection. Despite setting up CSRF token handling and ensuring that cookies are sent with requests, I'm still encountering a CSRF token mismatch error.
// axiosInstace.ts
import axios, { AxiosInstance } from "axios";

interface AxiosInstanceWithCsrf extends AxiosInstance {
  withCsrf: () => Promise<AxiosInstanceWithCsrf>;
}

const instance = axios.create({
  withCredentials: true,  // Ensure cookies are sent with requests
  baseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_ROUTE,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
}) as AxiosInstanceWithCsrf;

instance.interceptors.request.use(
  (config) => {
    console.log("Request config headers before sending:", config.headers);
    return config;
  },
  (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  },
);

instance.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    return response;
  },
  (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  },
);

instance.withCsrf = async function () {
  try {
    const response = await this.get("/api/csrf-token");
    const csrfToken = response.data.data.requestToken;
    this.defaults.headers.common["X-XSRF-TOKEN"] = csrfToken;
    console.log("Fetched CSRF Token:", csrfToken);
    return this;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching CSRF Token:", error);
    throw error;
  }
};

export default instance;

// register-user.ts
"use server";

import axios from "axios";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import instance from "@/axiosInstance";
import { User } from "@/types/index";

export const register_regulare_user_info = async (
  values: FormData,
): Promise<User | string | any> => {
  const cookieStore = cookies();
  const token = cookieStore.get("accessToken");

  const instanceWithCsrf = await instance.withCsrf();

  console.log("Authorization Token:", token?.value);
  console.log("CSRF Token:", instanceWithCsrf.defaults.headers.common["X-XSRF-TOKEN"]);

  try {
    const res = await instanceWithCsrf.post(
      "/api/users/register/regular",
      values,
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token?.value}`,
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
        withCredentials: true,  // Ensure cookies are sent with requests
      },
    );

    console.log("Response data:", res.data);
    return { success: res.data.data };
  } catch (error) {
    if (axios.isAxiosError(error)) {
      console.error("Error in axios register profile", error.response?.data);
      return { error: error.response?.data.errors };
    }
    console.error("Error in register user profile", error);
    throw error;
  }
};

The output is:
Request config headers before sending: Object [AxiosHeaders] {
  Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
Fetched CSRF Token: CfD.........................._jHKA
Authorization Token: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1N...................jnjHqgWp7Nemvs
CSRF Token: CfDJ..........................p_jHKA
Request config headers before sending: Object [AxiosHeaders] {
  Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  'X-XSRF-TOKEN': 'CfD............................otl9p_jHKA',
  Authorization: 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1N...........jnjHqgWp7Nemvs'
}
Error in axios register profile { message: 'CSRF token mismatch error', status: 'error', errors: [] }

When I try it with this code simple example, it works fine:
// utils/api.js
import axios from 'axios';

const apiClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://newdev.bazaarzone.net',
  withCredentials: true // Allow cookies to be sent with requests
});

export async function loginAndGetToken() {
  try {
    const response = await apiClient.post('/api/users/auth/phoneLogin', {
      userName: 'myusername',
      password: 'mypassword'
    });

    if (response.data.status === 'success') {
      return response.data.data.token;
    } else {
      throw new Error('Login failed');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error logging in:', error);
    throw error;
  }
}

export async function getCsrfToken() {
  try {
    const response = await apiClient.get('/api/csrf-token');

    if (response.data.status === 'success') {
      // Set CSRF token in axios default headers
      apiClient.defaults.headers['X-XSRF-TOKEN'] = response.data.data.requestToken;
      return response.data.data.requestToken;
    } else {
      throw new Error('Failed to get CSRF token');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error getting CSRF token:', error);
    throw error;
  }
}

export async function registerUser(authToken, userData) {
  try {
    const response = await apiClient.post(
      '/api/users/register/regular',
      userData,
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${authToken}`
        }
      }
    );

    if (response.data.status === 'success') {
      return response.data.message;
    } else {
      throw new Error('Registration failed');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error registering user:', error);
    throw error;
  }
}
 

// pages/register.js
import { useState } from 'react';
import { loginAndGetToken, getCsrfToken, registerUser } from '../utils/api';

export default function Register() {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    cityId: '',
    avatar: null,
    email: '',
    name: '',
    gender: '',
    userBio: '',
    dateOfBirth: ''
  });
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value, files } = e.target;
    setFormData((prevData) => ({
      ...prevData,
      [name]: files ? files[0] : value
    }));
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const authToken = await loginAndGetToken();
      const csrfToken = await getCsrfToken(); // Fetch the CSRF token

      const userData = new FormData();
      userData.append('CityId', formData.cityId);
      userData.append('Avatar', formData.avatar);
      userData.append('Email', formData.email);
      userData.append('Name', formData.name);
      userData.append('Gender', formData.gender);
      userData.append('UserBio', formData.userBio);
      userData.append('DateOfBirth', formData.dateOfBirth);

      const successMessage = await registerUser(authToken, userData);
      setMessage(successMessage);
    } catch (error) {
      setMessage('Registration failed');
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Register</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" name="cityId" placeholder="City ID" onChange={handleChange} required />
        <input type="file" name="avatar" onChange={handleChange} required />
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" onChange={handleChange} required />
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" onChange={handleChange} required />
        <select name="gender" onChange={handleChange} required>
          <option value="">Select Gender</option>
          <option value="Male">Male</option>
          <option value="Female">Female</option>
        </select>
        <textarea name="userBio" placeholder="User Bio" onChange={handleChange} required></textarea>
        <input type="date" name="dateOfBirth" onChange={handleChange} required />
        <button type="submit">Register</button>
      </form>
      {message && <p>{message}</p>}
    </div>
  );
}


